# CoreBluetooth CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse: Do requests return instantly or after write?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, core-bluetooth, synchronous

As the title suggests, I would like to know whether writes to CBPeripherals using CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse return instantly (and do the writing on another thread) or return only when the write is complete.

I would expect the latter, but a colleague of mine has given me reason to believe the former might be true (he's seeing packets not being sent by the iOS device when repeatedly writing).

Answer (score 1):

While Michal is right about the asynchronous nature of write request, I would like to elaborate a bit more on why packets might be not sent during repeatable writes without response.

I have recently experimented with BLE throughput under different conditions and found the following. When you repeatably write data for characteristic supporting write without response, it first gathers in the internal buffer. If you write too fast, this buffer overflows and all the data that doesn't make it into the buffer gets silently discarded. This has nothing to do with synchronous/asynchronous structure of BLE writes, it's just an iOS implementation of the internal buffer. As I figured out, on iPhone 6 running iOS 9 and connected to a single peripheral device, the available buffer size is around 3kb for uni-directional transfer, for bi-directional transfer its size decreases. So to prevent data loss you should ensure the buffer doesn't get overflown. You cannot control it at iOS side, but you can add some integrity checks to the data transfer protocol you use and orchestrate flow control from the peripheral side to e.g. retransmit lost packets.

It's funny, by the way, that in case of writes with responses you can write whatever large data to your characteristics (well, I didn't try too big values, but tried ones exceeding the MTU) and these data will be split into chunks and transmitted to the peer transparently for your code by iOS means without data loss. However, if the data sent to the characteristic will exceed MTU, you won't receive delivery callback.

Comment: Did you find any documentation on this internal buffer? In my case I don’t control the code on the peripheral, so would like to find a way to do flow control on iOS only. Any ideas (beyond adding a sleep to let packets go out?)

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Low Energy supports writing to the characteristic's value with or without response. In the latter case, the central won't receive any response from the peripheral, so it won't know whether write succeeded. In the former case, the central will be notified and Core Bluetooth will call `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:` method from `CBPeripheralDelegate`; in the latter case, this method won't be called.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:) says:

> When you call this method to write the value of a characteristic, the
>   peripheral calls the peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:
>   method of its delegate object only if you specified the write type as
>   CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse.

I understand your colleague may have thought that instead of getting the write result in delegate method, you will get it in the *return value*. But actually you won't get *any* write result when using `CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse`.

So writing to the characteristic's value will always be asynchrounous and the method will return immediately. If it didn't, it could block the main thread. And Core Bluetooth is designed to be used safely in from the main thread if you want to. For example, if you don't specify a dispatch queue for handling `CBCentralManager`'s events, it will handle them in the main queue by default.